# MS Access, SQL Server image field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ms-access

I have spent nearly 2 days in trying to figure this out. We have an Access Project (adp) from Year 2000 that stores images to SQL Server 2008. I have tried connecting directly to SQL Server and to open TIFF files but it didn't work. Also tried to copy/paste the image field content into a file, renaming as TIFF and trying to open it but it didn't work as well. The problem with the content in the image field is that it is not of the right size. It is only 15-20KB but the files at that point should be around 3MB. It works fine if I retrieve the same data back in to the ACCESS project application.

I have tried TiffLib.net and few other things.

So, has anyone got any idea on how to migrate those image fields into SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Share your MS Access code to see hot does it work.

Comment: are you *sure* they are tiffs?  something 15-20k would be a really small TIFF....

Comment: Perhaps the size discrepancy is Access compressing the image. Perhaps it's gzip'd before saving? The first few bytes of the binary blob might give away a file header.

Comment: If you're using SSMS results grid to "copy" the data, it might be due to the fact there is a restriction in the size of the data retrieved. Look at Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> Results To Grid -> Max Chars Retrieved section for Non XML Data.

Answer (score 1):

Well the Image data type stores a binary version of your image.
Now the conversion process is explain in the below links.
You'll need to use a library to convert a byte array into image object.

http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_load_blob.html

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103960-save-and-retrieve-images-with-sql-server/

Hopefully this helps.